# how to handle signal on windows with haskell?

Tags: haskell, signals

Is there something like  System.Posix on windows?

I want the code below to run on windows, should I change it?

```
import IO
import Control.Exception hiding (catch)
import Control.Concurrent
import Network
import System.Posix   ---cannot be run on windows.

main = withSocketsDo (installHandler sigPIPE Ignore Nothing >> main')
    --so the signal handler cannot be used

main' = listenOn (PortNumber 9900) >>= acceptConnections

acceptConnections sock = do
        putStrLn "trying to accept" -- debug msg
        conn@(h,host,port) <- accept sock
        print conn -- debug msg
        forkIO $ catch (talk conn `finally` hClose h) (\e -> print e)
        acceptConnections sock

talk conn@(h,_,_) = hGetLine h >>= hPutStrLn h >> hFlush h >> talk conn
```

for example ,if I want the program to quit when ctrl+c,I must add a handler for SIGINT ,so in c++,write some code like this:

```
void callback(int sig) 
{ 
   // printf("catch\n"); 
} 
... 
signal(SIGINT,callback);
```

But I don't know how to do this in haskell,use FFI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types

type Handler = CInt->IO ()
foreign import ccall "wrapper"
  genHandler:: (Handler) -> IO (FunPtr Handler)

foreign import ccall safe "signal.h signal"
        install:: CInt->FunPtr Handler->IO CInt
main=do
        s<-genHandler (\x->putStrLn $ "catch "++(show x))
        res<- install 2 s
        putStrLn $ show res
        s<-getLine
```

the code above is what i wanna do,just import the `signal` function,with a haskell callback.

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party, but I wrote a library which can help. It allow signal handling on both Windows and Linux. It is avaliable on hackage:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/signal

Answer (score 3):

I am not a Windows expert, so I don't know what you will need to do to ignore whatever event you're ignoring here. You'll probably want to poke around in the [Win32](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32) documentation for whichever version you have installed. However, I do know a bit about the build system and how to get one of two versions of a function to build. So the strategy will look like this:

1. Make two directories, `unix-src` and `Win32-src` (or some similar names).
2. In each directory, put a module `OSCompat` (or some similar name) containing something like this:

   ```
   -- unix-src/OSCompat.hs
   module OSCompat where
   import System.Posix
   ignorePipe = installHandler sigPIPE Ignore Nothing

   -- Win32-src/OSCompat.hs
   module OSCompat where
   import System.Win32
   ignorePipe = -- ???
   ```
3. In your `project.cabal` file, put something like the following in your `executable` block:

   ```
   if os(windows)
       build-depends: Win32
       hs-source-dirs: Win32-src
   else
       build-depends: unix
       hs-source-dirs: unix-src
   ```
4. Change your top-level module to look like this:

   ```
   import OSCompat
   main = withSocketsDo (ignorePipe >> main')
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do something like that on Windows. Windows is not Posix-compatible, so it does not support signals in full extent, e.g. it [does not support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shrib/archive/2008/05/23/signals-on-windows.aspx) sending signals to other processes. Also the number of signals available [is pretty limited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

If I understood correctly you are ignoring SIGPIPE to protect your program from exiting if its output was piped to another process and then that process terminates, right? Sorry, I don't know how to do this in Windows (and in fact you don't often see programs communicating through simple pipe on Windows).
If your signal handling is connected with sockets, [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/netfxnetcom/thread/ac626c1d-9449-4f4d-804f-115a1779b284) may help.